# Unreliable selenium script

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, search, automation

I am writing a selenium script to search https://ssllc.com/. The code seems to be unreliable and works only sometimes.

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome

from selenium.webdriver.common.keys 
import Keys

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions  # Import ChromeOptions here



# Define the base URL of the website

base_url = 'https://www.ssllc.com'

search_bar='#page-top > div > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > input[type=text]' #CSS_SELECTOR

items = '#gatsby-focus-wrapper > div.root > div > div > div > div.medium-8.columns.main-content > div.ais-Hits > ul '



# Define the list of search queries

search_queries = [ 
 'Unused+Sartorius+1000+Liter+BIOSTAT+CultiBag+STR+Single+Use+Bioreactor',


'3+x+V5/XCell+Repigen+Next+Gen+ATF+controllers',

'InSite+Integrity+Tester'

]



# Configure ChromeOptions

options = ChromeOptions()

options.add_argument('--headless')  # Optional: Run Chrome in headless mode for faster execution



try:

for search_query in search_queries:

    # Initialize Chrome WebDriver for each search

    with Chrome(options=options) as driver:

        # Load the website

        driver.get(base_url)

       

        # Find the search input field and enter the query

        search_input = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, search_bar)))

        search_input.clear()

        search_input.send_keys(search_query)

        search_input.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

       

        # Wait for the search results to load

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, items )))

       

        # Extract and print search results

        search_results = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, items )

        if search_results:

            print(f"Search results for '{search_query}':")

            for result in search_results:

                # Get the link to the search result

                #result_link = result.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('href')

                #print(f"{result.text.strip()} - {result_link}")

                print(result.text.strip())

                print()

        else:

            print(f"No search results found for '{search_query}'")

except Exception as e:

print("An error occurred:", e)
```

I have tried adding a new item that I know is on the website, and  it doesn't come up. For example, the bioreactor does not show up but the integrity tester does. They are both available on the website. Also the code does not work consistently. Sometimes no results show up at all. I assume this is due to the website being overloaded. My goal is to search for any keyword. And have all the related results come up.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

It's probable that your results are unreliable because the site is throttling you.

[image]

All of those warnings indicate that results are not being returned because the API over overloaded.

I noticed that you can actually just go directly to the search results by using a `query` parameter in the URL. This seems more robust than using the search box on the page.

I also introduced some delays because you want to avoid being throttled.

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions

import traceback
import time
import logging
import json

logging.basicConfig(
  level=logging.DEBUG,
  format='%(asctime)s [%(levelname)7s] %(message)s',
)
logging.getLogger("selenium").setLevel(logging.WARNING)
logging.getLogger("urllib3").setLevel(logging.WARNING)

BASE_URL = "https://www.ssllc.com"

SEARCH_QUERIES = [
    "Unused+Sartorius+1000+Liter+BIOSTAT+CultiBag+STR+Single+Use+Bioreactor",
    "3+x+V5/XCell+Repigen+Next+Gen+ATF+controllers",
    "InSite+Integrity+Tester"
]

RESULTS = []

options = ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument('--headless')

# Don't instantiate browser inside loop. Once is enough!
with Chrome(options=options) as driver:
    # Just open the base URL once too.
    driver.get(BASE_URL)
    try:
        for search_query in SEARCH_QUERIES:
            logging.info(f" Search term: {search_query}")

            query_url = BASE_URL+"/search/?query="+search_query
            driver.get(query_url)

            logging.debug("- Wait for results to load.")
            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((
                By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                ".ais-Hits > ul.ais-Hits-list"
            )))

            logging.debug("- Extract results.")
            search_results = driver.find_elements(
                By.CSS_SELECTOR,
                ".ais-Hits > ul.ais-Hits-list > li"
            )

            if search_results:
                logging.info(f"✅ Search results ({len(search_results)} items).")
                results = [result.text.strip() for result in search_results]
            else:
                results = []
                logging.warning(f" No search results found.")

            RESULTS.append({
                "search": search_query,
                "results": results
            })

            time.sleep(60)

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error("An error occurred:"+str(e))
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())

with open("search-results.json", "wt") as fid:
    json.dump(RESULTS, fid)
```

Here's the log of a run:

```
2024-02-24 08:06:47,910 [   INFO]  Search term: Unused+Sartorius+1000+Liter+BIOSTAT+CultiBag+STR+Single+Use+Bioreactor
2024-02-24 08:06:50,701 [  DEBUG] - Wait for results to load.
2024-02-24 08:06:50,721 [  DEBUG] - Extract results.
2024-02-24 08:06:50,740 [   INFO] ✅ Search results (4 items).
2024-02-24 08:08:10,910 [   INFO]  Search term: 3+x+V5/XCell+Repigen+Next+Gen+ATF+controllers
2024-02-24 08:08:12,979 [  DEBUG] - Wait for results to load.
2024-02-24 08:08:12,994 [  DEBUG] - Extract results.
2024-02-24 08:08:13,014 [WARNING]  No search results found.'
2024-02-24 08:09:33,014 [   INFO]  Search term: InSite+Integrity+Tester
2024-02-24 08:09:35,355 [  DEBUG] - Wait for results to load.
2024-02-24 08:09:35,370 [  DEBUG] - Extract results.
2024-02-24 08:09:35,383 [   INFO] ✅ Search results (3 items).
```

I wrote the results to a JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "search": 
"Unused+Sartorius+1000+Liter+BIOSTAT+CultiBag+STR+Single+Use+Bioreactor",
    "results": [
      "Unused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag STR Single Use 
Bioreactor\nManufacturer: Sartorius\nProduct Model #: 1000L Single-Use 
Bioreactor\nProduct Code: 337327\nUnused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag 
STR Single Use Bioreactor for sale. SSLLC offers a wide selection of used 
Bioreactors / Fermenters for your Used Lab Equipment needs.\nVIEW DETAILS",
      "Unused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag STR Single Use 
Bioreactor\nManufacturer: Sartorius\nProduct Model #: 1000L Single-Use 
Bioreactor\nProduct Code: 337326\nUnused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag 
STR Single Use Bioreactor for sale. SSLLC offers a wide selection of used 
Bioreactors / Fermenters for your Used Lab Equipment needs.\nVIEW DETAILS",
      "Unused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag STR Single Use 
Bioreactor\nManufacturer: Sartorius\nProduct Model #: 1000L Single-Use 
Bioreactor\nProduct Code: 337325\nUnused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag 
STR Single Use Bioreactor for sale. SSLLC offers a wide selection of used 
Bioreactors / Fermenters for your Used Lab Equipment needs.\nVIEW DETAILS",
      "Unused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag STR Single Use 
Bioreactor\nManufacturer: Sartorius\nProduct Model #: 1000L Single-Use 
Bioreactor\nProduct Code: 337329\nUnused Sartorius 1000 Liter BIOSTAT CultiBag 
STR Single Use Bioreactor for sale. SSLLC offers a wide selection of used 
Bioreactors / Fermenters for your Used Lab Equipment needs.\nVIEW DETAILS"
    ]
  },
  {
    "search": "3+x+V5/XCell+Repigen+Next+Gen+ATF+controllers",
    "results": []
  },
  {
    "search": "InSite+Integrity+Tester",
    "results": [
      "Unused Thermo Scientific inSITE Integrity Tester\nManufacturer: Thermo 
Fisher Scientific\nProduct Model #: 30-IN-1052 RG\nProduct Code: 332788\nUsed 
Unused Thermo Scientific 30-IN-1001 Filter Integrity Tester for sale. SSLLC 
offers a wide selection of used Analyzers for your Used Lab Equipment 
needs.\nVIEW DETAILS",
      "Unused Thermo Scientific inSITE Integrity Tester\nManufacturer: Thermo 
Fisher Scientific\nProduct Model #: 30-IN-1052 RG\nProduct Code: 332787\nUsed 
Unused Thermo Scientific 30-IN-1001 Filter Integrity Tester for sale. SSLLC 
offers a wide selection of used Analyzers for your Used Lab Equipment 
needs.\nVIEW DETAILS",
      "Unused Thermo Scientific inSITE Integrity Tester\nManufacturer: Thermo 
Fisher Scientific\nProduct Model #: 30-IN-1052 RG\nProduct Code: 332786\nUnused 
Thermo Scientific 30-IN-1001 Filter Integrity Tester for sale. SSLLC offers a 
wide selection of used Analyzers for your Used Lab Equipment needs.\nVIEW 
DETAILS"
    ]
  }
]
```